# For a graph $X = (V,E)$ that if $\alpha \in \ker \partial$ then every $x \in V$ has the same number of edges coming in as going out.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

For a graph $X = (V,E)$, prove that if $\alpha \in \ker \partial$, then every $x \in V$ has the same number of edges coming in as going out.

What I've tried is that since $\alpha \in \ker \partial$, where $\partial: C_1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to C_0(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is the group homomorphism defined to be $\partial (e) = t(e) - o(e)$ and $t,o: E^o \to V$ where $o(e)$ is the vertex of origin and $t(e)$ is the terminal vertex, that

$$t(e_1) + t(e_2) + \dots + t(e_n) = o(e_1) + o(e_2) + \dots + o(e_n)$$

We can subtract away all the $t(e_i)$ such that $t(e_i) = x$ for an arbitrarily fixed $x \in V$, in which case to balance the equation above we would have to subtract away an equal amount of $o(e_j)$. This doesn't prove that the remaining $o(e_j)$ are the ones we want though. I wanted to say that the sum of the remaining $t(e_i)$ is equal to $mx$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, which is true, but I don't really know how to show that each $o(e_j) = x$ as it could be the case that we are adding up other vertices, which sum to $x$. Am I going the right way? I need a nudge in the right direction

Comment: Please explain your notation. What is $\partial$? What is $t(e_i)$? What is $o(e_i)$?

Comment: $\partial$ is the homomorphism $\partial: C_1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to C_0(X, \mathbb{Z})$ were the domain is the 1-chains of edges and the codomain is the 0-chains of vertices.

Comment: Sorry $t(e_i)$ is the terminal vertice of the directed edge $e_i$ and $o(e_i)$ is vertice of origin for the edge $e_i$.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a distinguished $1$-chain, or is the hypothesis simply that $\partial$ has a non-trivial kernel?

Comment: Please do not *only* put the question statement in the title. The title should contain a summary, and the body of the post itself should contain a detailed question

Comment: The hypothesis is just that $\partial$ has non-trivial kernel

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is my first post here.

Comment: What is the relation between $\alpha$ and $x$?  The nearly useless title question doesn't have this information and the body of the Question, which should contain the actual question, doesn't have a statement of the problem.

Comment: @EricTowers $\alpha$ is any non-zero element of $\ker \partial$. I would change the post myself, but last time I made a change it was overwritten and I suspect the asker is in the process of addressing my comments

Comment: I'm very sorry, $x$ is a vertice incident to an edge of $\alpha$. Honestly, this is my first interaction with homology and formal sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is incorrect as stated. For example, consider the directed graph with adjacency matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}.
$$
Consider the element
$$
\alpha = e_{12} + e_{13} + e_{23}.
$$
It holds that $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\partial (\alpha) = 0$, but it is not true that each vertex has in-degree equal to its out-degree.

Comment: That is very weird to me. The textbook I'm reading uses this as a stepping stone to proving that every element of $H_1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ can be written as a sum of cycles. It was the only step I had a problem with and I guess I know why now.

Comment: @schloopmoop What is apparent from the way that you're asking the question is that you don't understand all of the definitions being used. I suspect that there are conditions on $\alpha$ that you have missed, or $\alpha$ refers to a specific element (probably $\sum_i e_i$) that is defined somewhere in the text.

Comment: @schloopmoop A key thing to keep in mind when starting in an unfamiliar field is to make sure that you are aware of all of the relevant information (even if you do not have an intuitive model/interpretation for this information yet).

Comment: I'm so very sorry. These are my first weeks working within the context of graph theory and my notation is obviously very sloppy. When $\alpha$ is a formal sum of edges in the homology group how to do say the vertices incident to the edges involved with $\alpha$? Those are the actual vertices I'm concerned with. Once again very sorry.

Comment: @schloopmoop There's really no need to apologize. I wouldn't be answering questions on a math forum if I resented people for being confused about unfamiliar, complicated things.

Comment: @schloop Honestly, I'm not very familiar with the terminology in this context. Sometimes an analogous set is referred to as the "support" of the element $\alpha$, but I'm not sure if that term is used at all in graph theory. Are you working out of a particular textbook/set of notes, or is all of this coming from notes you've taken from a lecture?

Comment: I'm doing an undergraduate thesis and my professor essentially handed me Topological Crystallography by Sunada and said to read a chapter a week and come back to talk about it, so I've been learning most it on my own through the textbook. We haven't really talked about formal sums in depth, but I feel like I have moderate intuition on what its supposed to be doing. I am having a bit of trouble doing algebra within the confines of these homology groups, mostly just trying to figure out what it means to be adding vertices or edges.

Comment: @schloop Well the fact that you're working out of a textbook is good news, at least. Now, wherever you found this statement, you can flip through as necessary and find exactly what is being stated about $\alpha$ and its relation to both the graph and $\partial$.

Comment: @schloop As for what it means to be "adding vertices", one perspective is that a sum of vertices really encodes a linear functional over the abelian group/vector space of functions of the form $f: V \to \Bbb Z$ or $f: V \to \Bbb R$. That is, the chain $\sum_{i}m_i v_i$ is really the function $\phi(f) = \sum_i m_if(v_i)$.

Comment: It says: "Express $\alpha$ as $\alpha = e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_n (e_i \in E)$ with $e_i \not = \overline e_j (i \not = j)$ . Since $\partial \alpha = 0$, we have $t(e_1) + \cdots + t(e_n) = o(e_1) + \cdots + o(e_n)$. This implies that for $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ the number of edges coming in x coincides with the number of edges going into x for every x."

Comment: @schloopmoop Ok, so in this case $\alpha$ refers to a specific (i.e. distinguished) element of $C_1$. In particular, it is the sum in which each edge has a coefficient of $1$.

Comment: @schloopmoop What does $\bar e_j$ mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113727/discussion-between-schloopmoop-and-ben-grossmann).

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that $x$ is a vertex along the chain $\alpha$, the claim is false as written.

Let $X$ be this graph, comprised of $0$-cells and $1$ cells, labelled as shown.

[image: triangle with a tail]

You should be able to show $H_1(X; \Bbb{Z}) \cong \langle A+B-C \rangle$.

---

Start by orienting the ends of each $1$-cell alphabetically, so

\begin{align*}
\partial A &= b - a  \\
\partial B &= c - b  \\
\partial C &= c - a  \\
\partial D &= d - c
\end{align*}

Then, from the ordered basis $(A,B,C,D)$ to the ordered basis $(a,b,c,d)$, $\partial$ is the linear map given by
$$  \begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  1 &  0 &  0  \\
 0 & -1 &  1 &  0  \\
-1 &  0 &  1 &  0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  1
\end{pmatrix}  \text{.}  $$

Applying the following $\Bbb{Z}$-invertible operations in the order given \begin{align*}
-\text{row $3$} + \text{row $1$} &\mapsto \text{row $3$}  \\
\text{row $3$} + \text{row $2$} &\mapsto \text{row $3$}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
we find that $A+B-C \in \ker \partial$.  It should also be no surprise that combinations of rows 1, 2, and 4 cannot produce zero vectors, so there are no more generators of $H_1$.

(If you are not thinking of the fragment of ($\Bbb{Z}$-module) linear algebra over the ring $\Bbb{Z}$ (since our homology coefficients are taken from that ring), you should be.)

---

Now it is clear that the $0$-cell $c$ is a vertex in (a representative of the equivalence class) $\alpha \in H_1(X; \Bbb{Z})$.  But $c$ has three incident edges in $X$.

Perhaps the statement of the question asks for the vertex degree in the subgraph that is (a representative from the equivalence class of) the chain $\alpha$.  This is also false.  This bowtie

[image: bowtie]

has first homology generated by two loops: the loop on the left and the loop on the right.  (Or the left loop and the whole graph, or the right loop and the whole graph, or any two linearly independent vectors in the $\Bbb{Z}$-module that is analogous to the one we studied above).  In any event, all elements of $H_1$ are (have a representative which is) incident on the vertex of degree $4$.  In particular, the cycle consisting of "drawing an '$\infty$'" on this entire graph is incident on four vertices of degree $2$ and one of degree $4$.